# jquery slideToggle() first row show

Tags: jquery

I would like to use slideToggle for a text just like a `read more` works. More spesific the first row is shown and when the client click to the div, the full text shows.

```
<div class="group-one-row">
    <div class="row-header">
        <p class="group-regular-header">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

$('.row-header').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().find('p').slideToggle();
});
```

With this code I can show/hide the full text but I need the first row to be shown always.

Comment: http://2015.grind.digital/m2/cafo/groups.php

This is the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should not use `.slideToggle()` in this case. Try to put a single wrapper around the `<p>` tags and set the `max-height` of this wrapper the same height as the line-height of a single line. Then overflow hidden en animate the `max-height` to about `1000px` (or calculate the total height using JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Give a unique id to each rows and then you make sure that that you will either toggle in a div that is not the first row or you will slide in the first row if it is not already visible.

```
$('.row-header').on('click', function() {

   var p = $(this).parent().find('p');

   if( $(p).attr('id') != 'idOfTheFirstRow' && $('p').is(':visible') )
       $(p).slideToggle();
});
```